# Message is not sent to all active subscribers when using spring-websocket and rabbitmq-stomp

Tags: rabbitmq, stomp, spring-websocket, spring-rabbit, rabbitmq-stomp

I have a web app based on spring websocket over stomp(powered by spring boot 1.5.1). And I'm using Rabbitmq(3.6.6) with stomp plug-in as full feature broker.

According to [the doc of stomp](https://www.rabbitmq.com/stomp.html), the message with destination from /topic/ will be delivered to all active subscribers.

> Topic Destinations
>
> For simple topic destinations which **deliver a copy
> of each message to all active subscribers**, destinations of the form
> /topic/ can be used. Topic destinations support all the routing
> patterns of AMQP topic exchanges.
>
> Messages sent to a topic destination that has no active subscribers
> are simply discarded.

But the behavior is **NOT** consistent with above declaration in my app!

I opened the same page in two browsers. Hence there are two clients connecting to the websocket server. Both of them subscribed the same destination starting with `/topic/`.

After I sent the message to destination `/topic/<route key>`, but only one client will receive the message. The two client will rotate to receive the messages from the same destination.

In my spring server side app, I send the messages to destination like below,

```
    @Secured(User.ROLE_USER)
@MessageMapping("/comment/{liveid}")
@SendTo("/topic/comment-{liveid}")
public CommentMessage userComment(@DestinationVariable("liveid") String liveid,
                                     @AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails activeUser, UserComment userComment) {
    logger.debug("Receiving comment message '{}' of live '{}' from user '{}'.",
            userComment,liveid, activeUser.getUsername());
    final User user = userService.findByUsername(activeUser.getUsername()).get();
    return CommentMessage.builder().content(userComment.getContent()).sender(user.getNickname())
            .senderAvatar(user.getAvatar()).build();
}
```

In my client side, it subscribes the durable topic like below,

```
$stomp.subscribe('/topic/comment-' + $scope.lives[i].id, function(payload, headers, res) {
                                // do something
                            }, {
                                'durable': true,
                                'auto-delete': false
                            });
```

Below is the configuration of websocket in my spring app,

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker

public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractSessionWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer<ExpiringSession> {

@Value("${stompBroker.host:localhost}")
String brokerHost;
@Value("${stompBroker.port:61613}")
int brokerPort;
@Value("${stompBroker.login:guest}")
String brokerLogin;
@Value("${stompBroker.passcode:guest}")
String brokerPasscode;
@Value("${stompBroker.vhost:myvhost}")
String brokerVHost;

@Override
protected void configureStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/live/ws").withSockJS();
}

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic/").setRelayHost(brokerHost).setRelayPort(
            brokerPort).setSystemLogin(brokerLogin).setSystemPasscode(brokerPasscode).setVirtualHost(brokerVHost);

    /**
     * Both of two subscribers can receive the message if using simple broker 
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic/");
     */
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}

@Configuration
public class WebSocketSecurityConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
        messages.simpDestMatchers("/app/*").hasRole("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean sameOriginDisabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

Is there any wrong of my configuration of RabbitMQ and Stomp plugin? It works well when using `SimpleMessageBroker` not RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was resolved by the discussion in [rabbimq-users group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/rabbitmq-users/rabbitmq-stomp%7Csort:relevance/rabbitmq-users/H7BPkN3YuUg/6afR9xmjAgAJ).

I was used durable subscriptions, with the same ID, the consumers become competitive consumers.

Either specifying the different client id when using durable queue or using auto-delete queue resolved the issue.